# Components on a new line will keep their margin-left, resulting in an ugly outcome in css

Tags: html, css, less, atom-editor

I'm debugging the Atom-editor, a user reported that buttons get stacked oddly if the window size becomes too small.

Note that in Atom, people are allowed to write plugins, and that the markup will differ per plugin.

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn">One</button>
        <button class="btn">Two</button>
        <button class="btn">Three</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn">Four</button>
        <button class="btn">Five</button>
    </div>
    <button class="btn">Six</button>
    <button class="btn">Seven</button>
</div>
```

[image: Example]

I've added a margin-bottom to all immediate children of the element, fixing part of the issue. See the `.less` below.

```
@import 'ui-variables';

.btn-toolbar > * {
    // @component-padding is 10px, for the people who don't know less.
    margin-bottom: @component-padding/2;     
}
```

[image]

However, as you can see there's still some whitespace at the second line that shouldn't be there. It's the margin-left of a `.btn-group` (buttons have this too, but there are only `.btn-group` elements shown misbehaving in the image).

Is there any way to remove that margin? I googled for selecting any newline, but all I found was the `::first-line` pseudoclass. Which is obviously not useful here.

Comment: It would help to see the HTML markup.

Comment: @ steveax Markup can be anything, since atom allows people to write their own plugins, and those plugins may use these classes, `.btn`, `.btn-toolbar`, `.btn-group` among others.

I will add the html specific to the example though.

Comment: Please give us a Fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `nth-of-type` pseudoclass?

To target the second `.btn-group` you would use something like:

```
div.btn-group:nth-of-type(2) {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

As you can't use `nth-of-type` the best solution for your case is to remove the `margin-left` and just use `margin-right` on the `.btn-group`

Comment: This will never work, since the width of a `.btn-toolbar`, `.btn-group` and `.btn` is variable, as well that I cannot possibly know which `nth` of any of those I need to style.

People use these classes to build plugins with, there is simply no way to predict which `nth` I have to target.

This solution would work in js, if I found a way to determine any line that isn't the first. I'm looking for a pure css (or less) solution.

Comment: Can't you remove the `margin-left` from `.button-groups` and use just `margin-right` then?

Comment: I absolutely can and it fixes the problem. Update your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Was thinking the same thing. Sounds like the best solution. and then use &:last-child { margin-right: 0; }